# photo upload inside active_admin interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, activeadmin

I wan't to add image upload field inside active admin interface.[This is the view where I want to be able get photo upload](http://gyazo.com/6b3499b9ba8333493b3ded73124ac226)

I tried some earlier suggestions [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566943/fields-for-images-dont-displays-in-active-admin-form)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  form :html => { :multipart=>true } do |f|
  f.inputs :new_product  do
  f.input :name
  f.input :price
  f.input :category
  f.input :description

  f.has_many :prod_images  do |p|
    p.input :photo, :as => :file, :label => "Image",:hint =>   p.template.image_tag(p.object.photo.url(:thumb)) 
    p.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove image'
  end
end

f.buttons
```

end

Using this example I got such error

```
undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

It says that error is from here `app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb where line #1 raised`
but how can I access that file, because in explorer it is not showing up?
Thanks

Comment: I found the way to open that file but  anyway there is nothing to edit or smth. :(

Comment: Attach whole error backtrace.

Comment: @ Michael Szyndel I can't add all here, instead I uploaded it on [here](http://failiem.lv/down.php?i=voarynq&n=backtrace.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building a prod image, like this.

```
f.has_many :prod_images, f.object.prod_images.build do |p|
```

Comment: I turns this error `undefined method ``build`` for /photos/original/missing.png:Paperclip::Attachment1`

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds removed, I was wrong. Can you add you `Product` model?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Edits You can find below this comment, I created my own answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get file upload field with this code

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
 form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
f.input :photo, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.photo.url(:thumb))
end
```

But now I can't add submit buttons :D So I am still working on it :)

**EDIT**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.input :photo, :as => :file
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

This just shows buttons like Create and Cancel, but not showing up file field, I checked formastic examples, but without success.

**EDIT2**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :description, :manufacturer_id, :name, :photo 
  extend FriendlyId
   has_attached_file :photo,
     :styles => {
     :thumb=> "100x100#",
     :large => "290x170",
     :medium=> "120x120"}

  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: It somehow just can show only one input field, if I wan't to add other inputs it shows only the last one. The same is with action buttons.

Comment: First of all - use code block, not inline code. See my edit for ref.

Comment: Second. How you expect this to work if you attach a SINGLE photo in a model an then trying to have multiple photos in a RELATIONSHIP in activeadmin? That ain't gonna work.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Please, review my edits, The code has changed. Now I have other problem. Review my edits, please!